# How to pass an array into a map? Syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, syntax

I need to do something like this:

```
$('#online-order').wcForms({id: '#online-order', to: 'contact', colors['red']: '#00F' });
```

But there is mistake in syntax. Please, tell me how i must pass it. Thanks!

Comment: Mistake is there, colors['red']: '#00F' its esey, but how it looks in right syntax :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Javascript has no associative arrays, if you want it that way, you need to use another object.

```
{id: '#online-order', to: 'contact', colors: { red: '#00F'} }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxc5e/1/)

You can access your `red` property like this:

```
var obj = {id: '#online-order', to: 'contact', colors: { red: '#00F'} };

console.log(obj.colors.red);
//or
console.log(obj['colors']['red']);
```

Comment: so, i've reach this by myself already. But whenever, thanks you a lot for focus.

Comment: @Ax Hm, then what is your question exactly?

Comment: No question, already. I just can't close this post before last a few minuts.